# Cannot create cache directory for Laravel project

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am trying to create my first Laravel project but i am having a problem with composer and some permissions (at least that's what i understand). 
When I open my cmd to create a new Laravel project , using this command (create-project laravel/laravel basicwebsite), I get an error. 
The error message is

> > “Cannot create cache directory C:\Mamp\htdocs/
> >     C:\Users\giorg\AppData\Roaming\Composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/,
> >     or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache”.
> >     [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr3tX.png)

I am still new and I don’t know much but it seems that my folders are not writable or something similar.
I am using MAMP and windows 10.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Its says the folder it is trying to create for cache doesn't have a writable permission you need to enable permission to write.

Answer (score 1):

If the folder is owned by root, even if you have admin privileges, you still dont have permission, this happens when you use sudo while installing composer.

It can be solved by

```
sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.composer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your composer installation, not the folder permissions.

You should probably install globally, but locally to your user, it should only be used by your user account and not by the web server

https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

**Or**

```
composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel basicwebsite
php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel basicwebsite
```